# How do I add fieldinput values to an object in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, inputfield, aura-attribute

Im working on a component where a table is generated by data entered into 3 input fields (Year, Make and Model). I have a function where the user's inputs are assigned to their corresponding variable which are then to be added to an object type attribute, GarageItems. This would then be used to populate the datatable in my component. How could I do this?

**Here's my Component:**

```
<aura:component>

       <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

   
       <aura:attribute name="YearInput" type="Integer"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdYear" name="CarYear" placeholder="Please type the Car's Year" value="{! v.YearInput }" />
           
       <aura:attribute name="MakeInput" type="String"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdMake" name="CarMake" placeholder="Please type the Car's Make" value="{! v.MakeInput }" />
       
       <aura:attribute name="ModelInput" type="String"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdModel" name="CarModel" placeholder="Please type the Car's Model" value="{! v.ModelInput }" />
   
   
       <aura:attribute name="GarageItems" type="Object"/>
       <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List"/>

       
       <div style = "height: 300px">
           <lightning:datatable
                   key-field="id"
                   data="{!v.GarageItems}"
                   columns="{!v.Columns}">
           </lightning:datatable>
       </div>

   
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit action" onclick="{! c.SubmitData }" />
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clear Fields" title="Clear action" onclick="{! c.ClearFields }" />

</aura:component>
```

**Here is my Controller:**

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) 
        {
             cmp.set('v.Columns', 
                     [
                         {label: 'Year', fieldName: 'CarYear', type: 'integer'},
                         {label: 'Make', fieldName: 'CarMake', type: 'text'},
                         {label: 'Model', fieldName: 'CarModel', type: 'text'}
                     ]);
        },
    
    
    SubmitData : function(component, event, helper) 
        {
            var Year = component.get("v.YearInput"); 
            var Make = component.get("v.MakeInput"); 
            var Model = component.get("v.ModelInput"); 
            
            if ((Year != "")&&(Make != "")&&(Model != ""))
                
                {
             //take year.make.model and add to GarageItems;
```

**This is where I'm having the issue**

```
         }
        
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        
    },

 ClearFields : function(component, event, helper)
    {
        component.set("v.YearInput", "");
        component.set("v.MakeInput", "");
        component.set("v.ModelInput", "");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GarageItems` should be a List, not an Object. You should also set a default value so you don't have to check if the list exists or not:

```
<aura:attribute name="GarageItems" type="List" default="[]" />
```

Now, in your code, you can add the value to the list. You need to first get the list of items, add the item, and then set the new value. That looks like this:

```
SubmitData : function(component, event, helper) 
{
    let items = component.get("v.GarageItems");
    var Year = component.get("v.YearInput"); 
    var Make = component.get("v.MakeInput"); 
    var Model = component.get("v.ModelInput"); 
    
    if (Year && Make && Model) {
        items.push({ CarYear: Year, CarMake: Make, CarModel: Model });
    }
    component.set("v.GarageItems", items);
},
```

---

Edit: your `key-field` attribute should be `keyField` in Aura, and you must also generate an ID for each row, or you'll get a runtime error.

Here's a full working example in an Aura component.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
           <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

   
       <aura:attribute name="YearInput" type="Integer"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdYear" name="CarYear" placeholder="Please type the Car's Year" value="{! v.YearInput }" />
           
       <aura:attribute name="MakeInput" type="String"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdMake" name="CarMake" placeholder="Please type the Car's Make" value="{! v.MakeInput }" />
       
       <aura:attribute name="ModelInput" type="String"/>
       <lightning:input aura:id="IdModel" name="CarModel" placeholder="Please type the Car's Model" value="{! v.ModelInput }" />
   
   
       <aura:attribute name="GarageItems" type="List" default="[]"/>
       <aura:attribute name="Columns" type="List"/>

       
       <div style = "height: 300px">
           <lightning:datatable
                   keyField="id"
                   data="{!v.GarageItems}"
                   columns="{!v.Columns}">
           </lightning:datatable>
       </div>

   
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit action" onclick="{! c.SubmitData }" />
   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clear Fields" title="Clear action" onclick="{! c.ClearFields }" />

</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) 
        {
             cmp.set('v.Columns', 
                     [
                         {label: 'Year', fieldName: 'CarYear', type: 'integer'},
                         {label: 'Make', fieldName: 'CarMake', type: 'text'},
                         {label: 'Model', fieldName: 'CarModel', type: 'text'}
                     ]);
        },
    
   SubmitData : function(component, event, helper) 
{
    let items = component.get("v.GarageItems");
    var Year = component.get("v.YearInput"); 
    var Make = component.get("v.MakeInput"); 
    var Model = component.get("v.ModelInput"); 
    
    if (Year && Make && Model) {
        items.push({ id: items.length+1, CarYear: Year, CarMake: Make, CarModel: Model });
    }
    component.set("v.GarageItems", items);
},

 ClearFields : function(component, event, helper)
    {
        component.set("v.YearInput", "");
        component.set("v.MakeInput", "");
        component.set("v.ModelInput", "");
    }
})
```

Comment: I added that and it went in error free but now neither button seems to work.

Comment: @ButtonPusher The table's key field is `keyField` not `key-field`. You need to make sure you're looking at the correct documentation (Aura vs. LWC).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I followed your instructions and again I have no errors but neither the table is populated on Submit nor the inputfields clear when I press Clear Fields.

Comment: I figured out the problem. All I needed to do was make it a lightning page. The issues I was having were with the lightning app preview. Works perfectly now. Thank you.